# Ruby - Date ranges (from first of this month to first of next month)

Tags: ruby, date

I want to have something like this:

By example: If the first date is 2012-02-01 (YYYY-MM-DD), the next date has to be 2012-03-01. So increment the month.
However, if the date is 2012-12-01, the next date has to be 2013-01-01.  I have managed to that doing `nextMonth=((thisMonth) mod 12)+1` and setting nextYear to `thisYear+1` if `thisMonth = 12`.

My question is: Can I do that easily using the Date library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Date#>>](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-3E-3E):

```
>> require 'date'
=> true
>> d = Date.new(2012,12,1)
=> #<Date: 2012-12-01 ((2456263j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
>> d >> 1
=> #<Date: 2013-01-01 ((2456294j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
>> (d..d>>1)
=> #<Date: 2012-12-01 ((2456263j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>..#<Date: 2013-01-01 ((2456294j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

If the start date is not the first of the month but you still need the end date to be the first of the following month, you can do this:

```
>> d = Date.new(2012,12,12)
=> #<Date: 2012-12-12 ((2456274j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
>> (d>>1) - (d.mday - 1)
=> #<Date: 2013-01-01 ((2456294j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

Comment: Awesome, I never knew about this! +1

Comment: Michael thanks for the answer.  How would I get that date though? So if I am on the 2012/12/23 and I want to get 2012/12/01 to do that operation?

Comment: @HommerSmith That would be `d - (d.mday - 1)`. :-) Please don't forget to upvote and/or accept this answer, it's SO etiquette to do so.

Comment: I am asking how would I get the actual date from the month I am in. Date.new(Actual Year,Actual Month,1)

Comment: `Date.today - (Date.today.mday - 1)` or `Date.new(Date.today.year, Date.today.month, 1)` if you wanna be more explicit.

Comment: I get this in 1.9.2p290 -- NoMethodError: undefined method `today' for Date:Class - But I have done it like this: Date.strptime('01', '%d')